# I want to run some code using Sympy. However, it says there is no such module

Tags: python-2.7, sympy, importerror

So when I run my program it says that sympy doesn't exist as a module. However, it is installed (see screenshot). I can run Sympy using a virtual python environment. However, then matplot does not work. This is so messed up. Every time I try to run some code with my Mac, it just prompts that import does not exist though it clearly does...

[image: ImportError sympy but requirement satisfied]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that pip and python are using two different versions of Python, you can look in the source code of pip (`which pip`).

You can try being explicit:

```
$ python -m pip install --user sympy
$ python -c "import sympy"
```

You may also want to look into using a Python distribution such as [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).